# ajax 'delete' button for rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to get an ajax 'delete' button to work.

The button is deleting the object from my database, but is not updating the index page. so, the deleted object is still present in index until you refresh the page.

In my view:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Fabric", delete_fabric_path(fabric), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true, :class => 'delete_fabric', class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm"%>
```

Routes:

```
delete "/fabrics/:id" => "fabrics#destroy", as: 'delete_fabric'
get "/fabrics/collection" => "fabrics#index", as: "index_fabrics"
```

Controller:

```
def destroy
  @fabric = Fabric.find(params[:id])
  @fabric.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to index_fabrics_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js { render layout: false }
  end
end
```

destroy.js.erb:

```
$('.delete_fabric').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
});
```

If anyone has an idea of where I am going wrong, it would be much appreciated! Thanks.

This is [the tutorial I was following](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-and-ajax.htm).

Server logs:

```
Started DELETE "/fabrics/46" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-17 15:57:22 +0800
Processing by FabricsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"46"}
  Fabric Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "fabrics".* FROM "fabrics" WHERE "fabrics"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 46], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/fabrics_controller.rb:70
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/fabrics_controller.rb:71
  Fabric Destroy (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "fabrics" WHERE "fabrics"."id" = $1  [["id", 46]]
  ↳ app/controllers/fabrics_controller.rb:71
   (6.3ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/fabrics_controller.rb:71
  Rendering fabrics/destroy.js.erb
  Rendered fabrics/destroy.js.erb (9.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 83ms (Views: 30.4ms | ActiveRecord: 8.6ms)
```

Full view:

```
<!-- SHOW FABRIC COLLECTION / FABRIC OPTIONS-->
<div class="card-deck">

    <% @fabrics.each do |fabric| %>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<%=fabric.image%>">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><%= fabric.fabric_name%></h5>
              <p class="card-text"><%= fabric.fabric_description%></p>
              <p class="card-text"><%= fabric.printed%></p>


<!--               Listing fibre types -->
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Composition: 

                        <% fabric.fibre.each do |fibre| %>
                            <%=fibre %>
                        <%end%>
              </small></p>


<!--               Listing colours -->
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Colours: 

                        <% fabric.colour.each do |colour| %>
                            <%=colour %>
                        <%end%>
              </small></p>


<!--               Listing suitable for -->
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Suitable For: 

                        <% fabric.suitable_for.each do |item| %>
                            <%=item %>
                        <%end%>
              </small></p>

<!--               Show page button -->
      <%= link_to "Full Details", show_fabrics_path(fabric), class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>

<!--              AJAX DELETE BUTTON IN PROGRESS-->

       <%= link_to "Delete Fabric", delete_fabric_path(fabric), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true, :class => 'delete_fabric'%>

<!--              AJAX DELETE BUTTON -->

            </div>
           </div>
      </div>

    <% end %>

</div>
```

Full, full view:

```
<!-- MODEL FOR UPLOAD FABRIC -->


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
</br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Add Fabric to collection
</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Fabric</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">



<!-- Form to add fabric -->
<%= form_with scope: :fabrics, url: new_fabrics_path, local: true do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :fabric_name %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :fabric_name %>

      <%= form.label :fabric_description %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :fabric_description %>

      <%= form.label :purchased_from %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :purchased_from %>

      <%= form.label :meterage %><br>
      <%= form.select :meterage, (0..500) %>

        <%= form.label :select_fibres %><br>
        <%@fibres.each do |fibre|%>
            <%= form.label fibre %>
            <%= form.check_box :fibre, {multiple: true}, fibre.to_s, nil %></br>
        <% end %>

        <%= form.label :main_fabric_colours %><br>
        <%@colours.each do |colour|%>
            <%= form.label colour %>
            <%= form.check_box :colour, {multiple: true}, colour.to_s, nil %></br>          
        <% end %>

        <%= form.label :suitable_for %><br>
        <%@suitable_for.each do |item|%>
            <%= form.label item %>
            <%= form.check_box :suitable_for, {multiple: true}, item.to_s, nil %></br>      
        <% end %>

        <%= form.label :printed? %><br>
        <%= form.check_box :printed %><br>

      <%= form.submit "Add Fabric" %>
    </p>

<% end %>  
<!-- Form to add fabric -->

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Fabric</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></br></br>


<!-- MODEL FOR UPLOAD FABRIC -->

<!-- FILTER BAR -->

<% if @filtered == true %>

    <%= form_with scope: :filter, url: filter_fabrics_path, local: true do |form| %>
        <p>
        <%= form.select(:fibre, ['Silk', 'Linen', 'Cotton', 'Bamboo'], {:prompt => "Fibre Type"}) %>
        <%= form.select(:colour, ['Blue', 'Yellow', 'Purple', 'Green'], {:prompt => "Select Colour"}) %>
        <%= form.select(:suitable_for, ['Pants', 'Skit', 'Shirt', 'Skirt'], {:prompt => "Suitable For"}) %>
        <%= form.submit "Filter Results" %> 
        </p>
    <% end %> 

<% else %> 

    <%= form_with scope: :filter, url: filter_fabrics_path, local: true do |form| %>
        <p>
        <%= form.select(:fibre, ['Silk', 'Linen', 'Cotton', 'Bamboo'], {:prompt => "Fibre Type"})%>
        <%= form.select(:colour, ['Blue', 'Yellow', 'Purple', 'Green'], {:prompt => "Select Colour"})%>
        <%= form.select(:suitable_for, ['Pants', 'Skit', 'Shirt', 'Skirt'], {:prompt => "Suitable For"})%>
        <%= form.submit "Filter Results" %> 
        </p>
    <% end %>   

<% end %> 
<!-- FILTER BAR -->

<!-- DISPLAYS CURRENTLY SELECTED FIELDS IF @FILTERED VIEW -->

<p><% if @filtered == true %>

    <% if @selected_fibre != "Fibre Type" %>
       <%= "Filtering by Fibre: #{@selected_fibre} "%>
    <% end %></br>  

    <% if @selected_colour != "Select Colour" %>
       <%= "Filtering by Colour: #{@selected_colour} "%>
    <% end %></br>  

    <% if @selected_suitable_for != "Suitable For" %>
       <%= "Filtering by Project: #{@selected_suitable_for} "%></p>
    <% end %></p>


 <%= link_to "Clear Filters", index_fabrics_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %><br><br>
<% end %>  


<!-- SWITCHES STATEMENT BASED ON FILTERED YES/NO-->
<% if @fabrics.length == 0 %>
    <h4> NO SEARCH RESULTS (PROMOTE FABRICS THAT MATCH SEARCH FROM RETAILER) </h4></br>
  <% else %>

    <% if @filtered == true %>
        <h4> OPTIONS FOR YOUR SEWING PROJECT</h4></br>
      <% else %>
        <h4> YOUR FABRIC COLLECTION</h4></br>
    <% end %>

<% end %>


<!-- SHOW FABRIC COLLECTION / FABRIC OPTIONS-->
<div class="card-deck">

    <% @fabrics.each do |fabric| %>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<%=fabric.image%>">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><%= fabric.fabric_name%></h5>
              <p class="card-text"><%= fabric.fabric_description%></p>
              <p class="card-text"><%= fabric.printed%></p>


<!--               Listing fibre types -->
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Composition: 

                        <% fabric.fibre.each do |fibre| %>
                            <%=fibre %>
                        <%end%>
              </small></p>


<!--               Listing colours -->
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Colours: 

                        <% fabric.colour.each do |colour| %>
                            <%=colour %>
                        <%end%>
              </small></p>


<!--               Listing suitable for -->
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Suitable For: 

                        <% fabric.suitable_for.each do |item| %>
                            <%=item %>
                        <%end%>
              </small></p>

<!--               Show page button -->
      <%= link_to "Full Details", show_fabrics_path(fabric), class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>

<!--              AJAX DELETE BUTTON IN PROGRESS-->

       <%= link_to "Delete Fabric", delete_fabric_path(fabric), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true, :class => 'delete_fabric'%>

<!--              AJAX DELETE BUTTON -->

            </div>
           </div>
      </div>

    <% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the server logs?

Comment: You need to remove `remote: true`, for the page to refresh.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna that is not the intention of OP. OP already has the JS to remove the deleted record from view. It just isn't working. Redirection is not a solution here.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I have added the logs! Have also fixed the double class issue in the view, although it hasn't solved it.

Comment: Can you add more context on the link for the deletion? The whole HTML markup for the Fabrib + The deletion link? Thanks

Comment: @Erowlin have added! Thanks!

Comment: @graciecatherine I can't see the `tr` closet to `.delete_fabric` anyway do you want to remove that record from full view? and that is the full view that you have posted in question?

Comment: @Erowlin yes have realised that I a looking for an element that doesn't exists, that being the closest 'tr' element. D'oh. Ho would I change the view code so it works, can I select the closes 'p' element instead? Or do I need to select the entire card?... Very confused here

Comment: @graciecatherine Just add a unique id for each record in fabric and on deletion of that record remove that element using that unique id, for details please find the given answer below and let me know for further guidance, also make sure you app has up and running jquery and if you get any error see at browser console and paste that in comment, i'll be happy to help you, thanks

Comment: @graciecatherine Is it working? by the way feel free to accept/upvpte answer if it helped you?

Comment: @Gabbar sadly no... Is it an issue with the js file? Cani write in ruby in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolandas solution should helps you resolve your issue.

On the server side, the deletion is properly happening and you're rendering the correct partial (the destroy.js.erb file.)

Additional debugging: Add a `console.log($(this).closest('tr'))` in your event listener for the `ajax success`.

Your javascript should looks like that:

```
console.log('Binding event');
$('.delete_fabric').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  console.log('fading the element: ', $(this).closest('tr')); 
  $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
});
```

- If you don't see a log in your JS console, it means that you're not listening to the correct event.
- If you see the console log, look at the element that will be faded-out, and checks it's the Fabric you just destroyed.

Comment: Nothing is coming up so I must not be listening to the correct event!

Comment: Oh oh I think it must be to do with  .closest('tr') just read up on the function. My elements are not <tr> on my view... ?

Answer (score 0):

You're defining class twice:

`:class => 'delete_fabric', class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm"`

try combining those two:

`class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm delete_fabric"`

Answer (score 0):

Add unique id for each `fabric` record i.e (`id="fabric_<%=fabric.id%>"`)

```
<!-- SHOW FABRIC COLLECTION / FABRIC OPTIONS-->
<div class="card-deck">
  <% @fabrics.each do |fabric| %>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" id="fabric_<%=fabric.id%>">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="<%=fabric.image%>">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"><%= fabric.fabric_name%></h5>
        <p class="card-text"><%= fabric.fabric_description%></p>
        <p class="card-text"><%= fabric.printed%></p>
        <!--Listing fibre types -->
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Composition: 
          <% fabric.fibre.each do |fibre| %>
          <%=fibre %>
          <%end%>
          </small>
        </p>
        <!--Listing colours -->
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Colours: 
          <% fabric.colour.each do |colour| %>
          <%=colour %>
          <%end%>
          </small>
        </p>
        <!--Listing suitable for -->
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Suitable For: 
          <% fabric.suitable_for.each do |item| %>
          <%=item %>
          <%end%>
          </small>
        </p>
        <!--Show page button -->
        <%= link_to "Full Details", show_fabrics_path(fabric), class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
        <!--AJAX DELETE BUTTON IN PROGRESS-->
        <%= link_to "Delete Fabric", delete_fabric_path(fabric), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true, :class => 'delete_fabric'%>
        <!--AJAX DELETE BUTTON -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In controller:-

```
def destroy
  @fabric = Fabric.find(params[:id])
  if @fabric.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Fabric deleted successfully!"
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to index_fabrics_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js { render layout: false }
  end
end
```

In destroy.js.erb

```
<%if flash[:success].present?%>
  $("#fabric_<%=params[:id]%>").fadeOut();
  //$("#fabric_<%=params[:id]%>").remove();
<%end%>
```

Comment: Dang, tried this but its still not working... Oh dear me.